# What OS X does Swift 2 work on?

Tags: xcode, swift, macos, swift2

I want to learn to code using Swift 2 but I am not sure if the operating system on my Mac is adequate. I am a beginner at programming so please forgive my naivety. Can I make apps to run on 10.8 (Mountain Lion) using Swift? Also could I download the appropriate software, e.g. Xcode, to learn to code in Swift and make apps using Swift even if I have 10.8.5?

I have been reluctant to upgrade my Mac as the reviews for El Capitan have been varied and the current version of Word that I have installed on my machine is not compatible with any operating system more advanced than 10.8.

The question that this has been marked as a duplicate of does not specify whether or not Xcode can be run on Mountain Lion.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Also would recommend updating your computer.... The security risks you're putting on yourself far outweigh the "bad reviews" of any newer OS

Comment: It isn't my decision, it's my Dad's. :\